# Kendo Grid Filter not working properly for date column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have taken a Kendo Grid with date column. Like below

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RxConnectEntities.OrderDTO>(Model).Name("OrderList")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Visible(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Drug).Width(60);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity).Title("Quantity (gm)").Width(80);
    columns.Bound(p => p.OrderedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("Ordered On").Width(80);
})
.Scrollable(s=>s.Height("100%"))
.Sortable()
.Groupable()
.Filterable(f => f.Extra(false).Operators(o => o.ForString(str => str.Clear().StartsWith("Starts with").Contains("Contains")).ForDate(c=>c.IsGreaterThan("Is after").IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Is after or equal to").IsLessThan("Is before than").IsLessThanOrEqualTo("Is before or equal to"))))
.Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new int[]{10,20,25,30,35}).Enabled(true).Refresh(true))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax().ServerOperation(false).PageSize(25)
.Model(m => m.Id(p => p.OrderID))
))
```

Now when I apply filter on OrderedDate, it don't work correctly. It doesn't work for equal to condition. I don't know what's the issue. Please help.

Comment: Did you check that minutes and seconds are the same? (You are only displaying Year, Month and Day but internally it uses Minutes, Seconds and Fractions of second as well)

Comment: @OnaBai is there anyway I can avoid it?

Comment: use the [DataType(DataType.Date)] above the OrderDate

Comment: If no other option available you can define your custom compare function that discards minutes and seconds. Do you want to try this approach?

Comment: @HadiHassan I can't set data annotation. Is there any other way?

Comment: @HadiHassan I found there is an option like EnableTimeIndependentFiltering in aspx. Is there anything like this in razor?

Comment: if you don't want to use the DataType on the orderdate because you want to use it somewhere else, you can make another readonly property that reads orderdate and mark datatype over it, it will help you, but i am afraid that you might using globalization without using the culture.js for kendo, are you using different date format?

Comment: @HadiHassan I tried as readonly property but still not getting right result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have to develop and check your property and then convert it in to DateTime and based on your requirement either you should fetch Date or DateTime.

For more clarity please check below code : 
Make another column as readonly column like below:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? UpdatedOrderedDateReadOnly 
{ 
    get
    {
        if (OrderedDate != null)
        {
            return (Convert.ToDateTime(OrderedDate).Date);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then apply filter on this readonly column. This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
.Filterable(f => f.Extra(false).Operators(o =>
{
    o.ForDate(t =>
    {
        t.Clear();
        t.IsEqualTo("Equal To");
        t.IsGreaterThan("Greater Than");
        t.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Greater Than Or Equal");
        t.IsLessThan("Less Than");
        t.IsLessThan("Less Than Or Equal");
    });
}))
```

hope that this will help you, i tried it and it worked with me

regards

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this until I found the Gist on github

Here is the [article](http://www.crowbarsolutions.com/ignoring-time-when-filtering-dates-in-telerik-kendo-grids/) on how to go about this.

Read the comments and you will see that Telerik thinks it is working as designed.  Unfortunately it doesnt work for only filtering by date.  Big nod to Crowbar Solutions.